# realloc function don't save new elements with new values in c

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

function gets an array of grades and changes the amount of grades if there are less elements than before the function will delete those elements
for example: before: I entered in another function 3 grades: 100, 90, 80.
after: In this function it asked me to enter new amount, and I entered, and then entered it's grade, 70.
after I return it to the main and sending the array, grades, to a function which prints the array and it's stays with 3 elements, 100, 90, 80.
please help me i tried a lot of time and didn't succeed.

```
void changeNumOfGrades(int* grades, int size)
{
    int numOfGrades = 0;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        if (i > ONE_ITERATION)
        {
            printf("Please enter positive number...\n");
        }
        printf("How many elements would you like? ");
        scanf("%d", &numOfGrades);
        i += 1;
    } while (numOfGrades < 0);
    grades = realloc(grades, numOfGrades*sizeof(int));
    if (!grades)
    {
        printf("Unsuccessful realloc");
        //There is no need to release memory because the realloc is for the same pointer.
    }
    if (numOfGrades > size)
    {
        printf("You have more grades than before,\nPlease enter their grades: \n");
        int newGrade = 0;
        //int newNumOfGrades = numOfGrades - size;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = size + 1; i <= numOfGrades; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter grade number %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &newGrade);
            *(grades + i - 1) = newGrade;
            printf("hey %d", *(grades + 1));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the
corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the
arguments.[...]*

Comment: This function signature: 'void changeNumOfGrades(int* grades, int size)' cannot change the value of the '*grades' argument because it's passed by value.

Comment: What is the value of the `grades` pointer *before* you call `realloc()`?  What is the value *after*?  What is the value of the pointer *in `main()`* before your call to `changeNumOfGrades()`?  What is the value of the pointer in `main()` *after* your call to `changeNumOfGrades()`?

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to reallocate grades, you need to pass as `**grades`.
For test reasons, I have changed `size` to get the new allocation size, so you can print the array after the changeNumOfGrades

```
void changeNumOfGrades(int** grades, int *size/*get new size*/)
{
    int numOfGrades = 0;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        if (i > ONE_ITERATION)
        {
            printf("Please enter positive number...\n");
        }
        printf("How many elements would you like? ");
        scanf("%d", &numOfGrades);
        i ++;
    } while (numOfGrades < 0);
    printf("%d",numOfGrades);
    *grades =  realloc(*grades, numOfGrades*sizeof(int));/*realloc **grade */
    if (!grades)
    {
        printf("Unsuccessful realloc");
        //There is no need to release memory because the realloc is for the same pointer.
    }
    printf("...\n");
    if (numOfGrades > *size)
    {
        printf("You have more grades than before,\nPlease enter their grades: \n");
        int newGrade = 0;
        //int newNumOfGrades = numOfGrades - size;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = *size + 1; i <= numOfGrades; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter grade number %d: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &newGrade);
            *(*grades + i - 1) = newGrade;
            //printf("hey %d", *(grades + 1));
        }
    }
    *size = numOfGrades;/*get new size allocated*/

}

void main()
{
    int numOfInts;
    int *grades ;
    grades =  malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    memset(grades,0,sizeof(int)*3);
    grades[0]=100;
    grades[1]=80;
    grades[2]=20;
    numOfInts = 3;/*initialize 3 items*/
    changeNumOfGrades(&grades,&numOfInts);
    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i=0;i<numOfInts;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",grades[i]);
    }
    free(grades);
}
```